# SSRS - Sub Totals Customization - Moving Column to beginning of line

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I Have a request for the TOTAL's and subtotals column to be moved to the top/left of columns it represents, and by default SSRS does it on the bottom or right hand side of the columns being totaled.  Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own solution, when you right click on the tiny green triangle, in the top right hand corner of the sub total column.  Then select properties, and you can adjust the "Layout" property.. it has 2 options, Before and After.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a row which comes before your set of data, for each field you want to total just give that cell an expression which does a SUM() of that particular field.